# How do you change the size of the components in a uipicker

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have a picker returning 3 components. I was told you can change the size of the views by doing the following, but I am not too sure how to implement this...
implementing the UIPickerViewDelegate method pickerView:widthForComponent: method to size the components (probably 150, 20, and 150, or so).

I see in the documentation you set up a method like this, but dont know what to do next?

```
- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView widthForComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For using this you have to implement `UIPickerViewDelegate`...... and assign it to your `pickerView`.....

if this method is being written in the same class where you are creating `pickerView`......
then write.....

```
pickerView.delegate = self;
```

and in header implement this delegate...

```
- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView widthForComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if(component == 0)
       return 150.0;
else if(component == 1)
       return 20.0;
else if(component == 2)
       return 150.0;
else
       return 150.0;

}
```

Components are numbered left-to-right.

Thanks,

Comment: @User I wanna set the compenants in the picker view custom to the first one 150, the second 20, and the third 150